# How to extract key and value from r=requests.get('http....')

Tags: api, rest

So, i got

```
 r=requests.get('http....')
 r=r.json() // here I got json (probably)
```

then I want to print 'body' from this json

```
print(r['body'])
```

and i got eror: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: `r` is a list (`[...]`). Lists can't be indexed with strings. You seem to expect an object `{"body": ...}`. You'll have to share the JSON.

Comment: I didn't get it, sorry

Comment: Basically, to get my key - value, I need operate with dictionary.
But r.json() - is a list ( I don't realy know why, most of the documentation specified as a dictionary

Comment: I assume this is the JSON returned by the request. If that's the case, you have to provide the docs of the API you're accessing.